# Периодический опрос сервера

Tags: android

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, как более правильно сделать опрос сервера на наличие какой либо информации. Например, сейчас я применяю сервис, а в сервисе объявляю Timer, который с определенной периодичностью стучится на сервер. Т.к сервис это отдельный поток + в нем Timer (еще один поток), то получается некоторая избыточность (зачем создавать 2 потока, когда можно опросить сервак в одном). С  AsyncTask та же история, если я хочу обращаться периодически, то использую Timer (получается 2 потока).

Comment: А чем не устраивает alarmManager? Никакого sleep, да еще телефон разбудить может)))

Comment: А если правда частый опрос, все равно использовать alarmManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если опрашивать нужно часто (допустим каждые 2-3 минуты), тогда хорошим решением будет постоянно работающий поток в сервисе, который в перерывах просто делает sleep на минуту-две.

Если нужно запускать раз в час-полтора (например, для синхронизации списка новостей), тогда более оптимальным решением будет [специальный сервис](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). Плюсы - не нужно беспокоится, что Ваш сервис упадет и не подымется больше. Также можно настроить "неравномерное обновление". То есть, сервису говорим "запускай раз в сутки утром, в районе 7 часов утра". На одних устройствах синхронизация будет запускаться в 7:00, на других

Comment: спасибо друг. тоже думал о sleep но мне показалось это каким то костылем....

Answer (score 2):

Для современного подхода опрашивать сервер - не комильфо. Есть вариант когда сервер сам рассылает информацию, когда она одновиласть. Это websocket. Android с ним очень хорошо дружит.

Comment: ммм а как он сможет отослать информацию если Android находиться за NAT ?

Comment: А какие проблемы?

Comment: ну  у Android нет  белого ip, как я могу соединиться?

Comment: если у него нет белого ip он что в инет не выходит? почитай про websocket. единственное ограниченеие это старые прокси, но и это решается с помощью wss.

Comment: тут более правильный вопрос что за сервер, если это сторонний сервер, то тады ой. тогда только выбирать варианты по опросу.

Comment: Самый правильный способ решить эту проблему — push notifications. GCM поддерживает отправку довольно больших объёмов данных, и позволяет интерпретировать её на клиентской стороне очень подробно. Библиотеки для создания GCM-сервера есть под все широко распространённые сервачные языки.

Comment: @Вадим, да и со своим сервером в нативном приложении WS - не лучший вариант. Это как минимум внешняя библиотека. Я хороших, честно говоря и не видел. Ну и морока с определением, когда WS открыть и когда - закрыть.

Comment: @lsillarionov Вот уж с чем а с ws мороки нет. открыл ws и забыл о нем. Надо послал сообщение. Есть на сервере - получил. Отключил сеть - на сервере собщение о закрытии с кодом - либо по обрыву, либо по желанию - можно обрабатывать, а можно и нет. У меня есть библ. не работа, а удовольствие - к серваку можно подключать и андроид и браузер - ему одинаково.